# Pivoting one level of index in multilevel index

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe with a multi-index:

```
                   col1   col2
 date        id    
 2016-04-05   A     100     99
 2016-04-05   B     101     98
 2016-04-05   C     102     95
 ...
 2016-04-12   A      90     65
 2016-04-12   B      91     62
 2016-04-12   C      93     64
```

How do I take col1 and pivot the 'id' level of the index into a frame where the index is only 'date' and the columns are the values of 'id'?

```
       date     A     B     C 
 2016-04-05   100   101   102
 2016-04-06    80    87    83
 ...
 2016-04-12    90    91    93
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can first [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) `col2`, then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html),  [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.drop('col2', axis=1).unstack('id')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
df = df.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
print df
        date    A    B    C
0 2016-04-05  100  101  102
1 2016-04-12   90   91   93
```

Next solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
print df.reset_index()
        .pivot(index='date', columns='id', values='col1')
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .reset_index()

        date    A    B    C
0 2016-04-05  100  101  102
1 2016-04-12   90   91   93
```

Comment: drop col2 from df before unstack, then your answer is just it :-)